# django join to model with same User

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to connect the post model with the `userImage` so the I can jointly represent `post` and corresponding to it the related `user image` must be displayed.

Please tell me how to generate the query.

**views**

```
instance = postmodel.objects.order_by('-updated')
```

**model userImage:**

```
class userImage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profileimage = models.ImageField(upload_to="userprofile/")
```

**model that contain post detail:**

```
class postmodel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None)
    body=models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    subject=models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
```

Comment: Why is there an "_enter code here_"? Looks like you copy-pasted this from a test.

Comment: Can one `User` have multiple `userprofile`? Is not, you should use a one-to-one field instead of `ForeignKey`.

Comment: And your code would be _much more readable_ if you followed the simple and sensible naming convention that all class names should be capitalized. So `UserProfile` instead of `userprofile` and `PostModel` or `Post` instead of `postmodel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ideally** every user should have one profile. So, `userprofile` model should  be connected to `User` model using **OneToOneField**

```
class userImage(models.Model):
    user = models.models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profileimage = models.ImageField(upload_to="userprofile/")
```

You can get the posts and then use it like below.

```
posts = postmodel.objects.all().order_by('-updated')
```

**html:** Get all the post content along with title and `user image` this way.

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>

    <img src="{{post.author.userimage.profileimage.url}}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Rishavagarwal, Have you tried this?? It should work for you.

Comment: please clarify why we can not use the foreign key instead of onetooneFiled.

Comment: Because every user should have one profile. `ForeignKey` is for one-to-many but, I don't think you will ever want to have more than 1 profile for a single user.

Comment: how can we do this by using foreignkey .Is it possoble or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to "get" the postmodel object to get an instance

`instance = postmodel.objects.get(...)
profile_image = instance.author.profileimage`

otherwise run a for loop on the queryset

`posts = postmodel.objects.order_by('-updated')
for post in posts:
    image = post.author.profileimage`